# Birt: Insufficient memory to execute a report

Tags: java, tomcat, birt, birt-emitter

I'm using Birt 4.4.0 and calling a Java class to run the reports. The sql statement returns not more than 100 lines but I'm getting *There is insufficient memory to execute this report* error.

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask handleFatalExceptions
SEVERE: There is insufficient memory to execute this report.
```

I tried to increase the both heap space and permGen memory on catalina.bat file by  -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the relevant code in the Java class?

Comment: Are you trying to run it in BIRT or are you calling the report as web page through Apache?

Comment: You should tell us which DB you are using and how you are actually calling BIRT. Note that BIRT >= 4.2.2 doesn't work with Oracle, depending on your queries and depending on the JDBC driver.

Comment: @hvb I'm using Oracle and calling the report as a web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, while writing the comment I remembered that last year I had a similar problem: Even the most simple queries caused memory problems.

**Note: This answer is only valid if your application is using an Oracle DB.**

In my case, my application (and the Eclipse BIRT IDE) was using Java 7.

If you are using Java 7, you should use the latest `ojdbc7.jar` from Oracle (*not* `ojdbc6.jar`). 
I finally found this out after several hours of struggling around with BIRT while my clients were watching.

Also note https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407299, which you might hit depending on your query.

Comment: Out of curiosity: ... nailed it regarding ojdbc7.jar or the bug?